# Manager isn't accessible via (....) instances

Tags: django, django-views

I have two tables namely Stuff and Boss. Based on the slug(user_type) from the user, I define which table is going to be used.

```
def Person_info(request,user_type):
    if user_type=="Staff":
        item=Staff()
    elif user_type=="Boss":
        item=Boss()

.................
```

Then, I need to get the last id for item from its table.

But, I am having  "Manager isn't accessible via Staff instances" When I try to get the last id of Staff table.

How can I bypass this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are querying using the instance, which is incorrect.

Change your code as below:

```
def Person_info(request,user_type):
if user_type=="Staff":
    # Note no () at the end, which makes the item an instance by instantiating it, not a class by assigning it
    item=Staff
elif user_type=="Boss":
    item=Boss
....
```